# Is it possible to use linq in ngIf in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'd like to use linq in ngIf but I'm getting an error.

Typescript:

```
public selectedStrategies: IStrategy[] = [];
```

html:

```
<div *ngIf="selectedStrategies.find(s => s.id === 3)">
  ...
</div>
```

Error:

Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 28 in [selectedStrategies.find(s => s.id === 3)]

Is this not allowed or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Note that there is no LINQ in JS/TS, it is only available in C#. I believe what you mean is Array function.

Comment: You can write your logic in a function in the component. Then call that function in the view. Example: `findStrategy(id: number) { return this.selectedStrategies.find(s => s.id === id)  };`, `<div *ngIf="findStrategy(3)">`

Comment: @YongShun Regarding Linq vs Array function, thank you. I figured it wasn't called Linq in TS world but I couldn't find anything that told me what it was called. And regarding creating a function in the TS and calling it from ngIf, that's what I ended up doing so I gather the answer is, no, it's not possible to use an array function in ngIf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We/I might need more information about what you are trying to do, but you could skip the `find` call and just set a property call `current` or whatever you are wanting to call it, and then just update that property as needed.

To answer your main question, no, it isn't possible to call chainable array methods within an `ngIf` or `@if`.

There are a few ways to do this though.

One way would be to use angular's new `signal` system with the `computed` signal that would update everytime one of the signals changes:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="current() as itm">Item: {{ itm.name }}</div>
    <p>
      <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="id" />
    </p>
  `,
})
export class TestComponent {
  id = signal(3);

  items = signal([
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' },
  ]);

  // Whenever any of the signals updates this will also update.
  // Don't update signals here or you could end up in an endless loop.
  current = computed(() => this.items().find(item => item.id === this.id()));
}
```

Another way would be to use a pipe and you could pipe the data through, this is good for not having to re-render hundreds of times as a function often will do.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'find', standalone: true })
export class FindPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform = (value: IStrategy[], id: number) => value.find(item => item.id === id);
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FindPipe],
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="items | find: 3 as itm">
      {{ itm.name }}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TestComponent {
  items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' },
  ];
}
```

Another way is to have a single property and set the current state on that property:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  standalone: true,
  template: `<div>{{ current.name }}</div> `,
})
export class TestComponent {
  items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' },
  ];

  current = this.items[0];

  setCurrent(id: number) {
    this.current = this.find(item => item.id === id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The simplest way to handle this is to write a method to call the find method on the array, but this is educational and I have a definitive answer to my question.

Comment: Calling a method directly from the template is bad practice (unless it is a `pure` function such as a pipe or signal), as it could potentially be called 100s/1000s of times causing your application to become slow.